# What is a function that is discontinuous, yet the bisection method converges?

Tags: numerical-methods

Also what about a function for which it diverges?

I was thinking f(x) = 10 + 1/x would work for where it converges, but can't think of one where the bisection method diverges at near a root. Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is not continuous, the assumption that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ has opposite signs doesn't imply that $f$ has a zero in $[a,b]$. Take for example something like

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & -1 \le 1/\pi \\ -1, & 1/\pi < x \le 1\end{cases}.
$$

Then the bisection method (starting with the interval $[-1,1]$) would converge to $1/\pi$ which is not a zero of $f$.

Changing the value of $f(1/\pi)$ to $0$ would give you an example when the method converges to a zero, even when $f$ is not continuous at that point.

In one sense, the bisection method *always* converges, since the gap between the points is halved in each step, which means that the limit of the endpoints of the interval converge to a common point (but that point need not be a zero of $f$ if $f$ fails to be continuous).